# How to multiply rows over a window in pyspark?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I want to implement the following formula using pyspark:

## `Lx_BOP(1) = 1`

## `Lx_BOP(n+1) = Lx_BOP(n) * (1 - rate(n))`

I created this test data:

```
termination_rate_input = [
    ["dummy_rate_flag", 1, 0.1],
    ["dummy_rate_flag", 2, 0.1],
    ["dummy_rate_flag", 3, 0.1],
    ["dummy_rate_flag", 4, 0.1],
    ["dummy_rate_flag", 5, 0.1],
]

input_schuma = StructType([
        StructField("rate_flag", StringType(), True),
        StructField("months_since_event", IntegerType(), True),
        StructField("bop_monthly_scaled_rate", DoubleType(), True)
        ])
```

and this logic:

```
def add_lx(rate_df):
    df = rate_df

    lx_window = W.partitionBy("rate_flag").orderBy(F.col("months_since_event"))
    # Add bop_monthly_scaled_rate(n) to n+1 row
    df = df.withColumn(
        "_n_bop_monthly_scaled_rate",
        (F.lit(1) - F.lag(F.col("bop_monthly_scaled_rate"), offset=1, default=1).over(lx_window)))
    df = df.withColumn(
        "_n_bop_monthly_scaled_rate",
        F.when(F.col("months_since_event") == F.lit(1), F.lit(1)).otherwise(F.col("_n_bop_monthly_scaled_rate")))
    # compute lx_bop based on _n_bop_lx and the bop_monthly_scaled_rate(n)
    df = df.withColumn(
        "lx_bop",
        F.exp(F.sum(F.log(F.lag(F.col("_n_bop_monthly_scaled_rate"), offset=1, default=1.0))).over(lx_window)))
    return df
```

this part `F.exp(F.sum(F.log(F.lag(F.col("_n_bop_monthly_scaled_rate"), offset=1, default=1.0))).over(lx_window)))` is used to multiply each cell in row(n) with the cell in row(n-1).

but I am getting an exception of:
`java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Cannot generate code for expression: lag(CASE WHEN (input[1, int, true] = 1) THEN 1.0 ELSE (1.0 - input[3, double, true]) END, 1, 1.0)`

Any other way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

The log of a product is the sum of the logs. But watch out for the bases, you can't just mix them. This below uses `e`, so power of `e` and natural logarithm.

`ln (x*y) = ln x + ln y`

So: `x * y = exp(ln (x*y)) = exp(ln x + ln y)`

`exp` and `log` exist as built in functions.
If you give only one argument to `log`, it does a natural log: [docs](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.functions.log.html)

So for the product you're looking for, you can use:

```
F.exp(F.sum(F.log(col)).over(window))
```

Answer (score 0):

Error is in the last row. we need to multiply the rows so we should drop the lag function.

```
df = df.withColumn(
        "lx_bop",
        F.exp(F.sum(F.log(F.col("_n_bop_monthly_scaled_rate"))).over(lx_window)))
    return df
```

Since spark doesn't have a multiply function we need to use F.exp(F.sum(F.log(SOME_COLUMN)).over(window))

Comment: You should accept the answer, since it solves your problem. I just spent time trying to understand your question, thinking this answer may have been an addition to the question.

Answer (score 0):

this could be done with the following code:

from pyspark.sql import functions as F

```
F.coalesce(F.exp(F.sum(F.log(col)).over(window)), F.lit(1.0))
```

Answer (score 0):

As of Spark 3.1.0 *aggregate* can be used
http://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.1/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.functions.aggregate.html

```
df = df.withColumn('cum_multiply', f.aggregate(f.collect_list('column_to_multiply').over(w), f.lit(1.0), lambda acc, x: acc * x))
```